# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "If": syntax error (code 1)

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm developing android Using SQLite , When inserting I'm having android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "If" ... This is my code :

```
String query =
            " If Exists(Select " + orderID + " From Print Where " + categoryNum +  "= " + itemID + " and "  + orderID + " = " + holdedOrderID + " )" +
            " BEGIN " +
            " UPDATE Print Set " + qty +  " =  " + qty + "+ " + QTY + 
            " Where " + categoryNum +  "= " + itemID + " and "  + orderID + " = " + holdedOrderID +
            " END " +
            " Else   " +
            " BEGIN  " +
            "  Insert Into orderDetails ( " + PRODUCT_NAME +","+ categoryName +","+ categoryNum +","+ orderID +","+ price +","+ qty + " , " + tabelNumber     +")"   
            + "   Values                  (" + "'" + itemName + "'" +","+  "'" +itemCategory + "'" +","+ itemID +","+  "'" + holdedOrderID +  "'" + ","+ itemPrice +","+ QTY  +","+  "'" +tableNumberz +  "'" + ") " +    
            "  END";
    mDb.execSQL(query);
```

Comment: @FrankN.Stein where to type the if else in the answer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite has no IF statement.

But by a weird coincidence, Java has it:

```java
String selection = categoryNum +  "= " + itemID + " and "  + orderID + " = " + holdedOrderID;
if (DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(mDb, "Print", selection) > 0) {
    mDb.execSQL("UPDATE ...");
} else {
    mDb.insert(...);
}
```